# Magento 2: How to change country name?

Tags: magento2, countries

I changed magento2 country name but didn't worked.

I changed in the below file:

> File: vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/xx.xml

How to change the country name ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to change the country name taiwan to china taiwan

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

Because of the changes in 2.4 being applied in the core translation file `app/code/Magento/Config/i18n/en_US.csv` We can override it at the theme level.  Create a custom translation CSV file here `app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Name>/<Theme_Name>/i18n/en_US.csv`  in your active theme(s) with the content `"Taiwan","Taiwan"` and do a cache flush.